# Mathjobs.org Generic Reference Letter

Tags: mathematics, recommendation-letter

I am applying for mathematics postdocs through Mathjobs.org. I have mentioned
names of three of professors for reference letter. One of professors asked me 
about whether should I submit a generic letter or a specific letter?

I have no idea about how does Mathjobs.org work and what should I tell my
professor? Any advise, comments will be helpful to me.

Comment: A reference can either upload a generic letter that all your applications can use, or they can upload specific letters to each prospective employer (they can't do this until after you actually start the application for that employer though). Specific is always best if the reference will write a strong letter.

Comment: Writing specific letters is a rather time-consuming task. If one of your recommenders wants to provide specific information to one or another of the places you're applying to, it would probably be easier and at least as effective to keep the MathJobs letter generic and to write a separate email to the people who would be your supervisors at those particular places.